# send cookies inside post request

Tags: python, post, cookies

trying to send Post request with specific cookies that on my pc from get request

i searched in google then i found

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener() # send the cookies
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies)) # send the cookies
f = opener.open("http://example")
```

this code is useful and helped me

but can someone explain it for me and tell me if **f variable**  makes request ?

i don't need cookielib just my example :)

if i typed

url = 'http://example' # to know the values type any password to know the cookies

```
values = {"username" : "admin",
          "passwd" : "1",
          "lang" : "" ,
          "option" : "com_login",
          "task" : "login",
          "return" : "aW5kZXgucGhw",
          } # request with the hash

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read()
cookies=response.headers['set-cookie'] #to get the cookies
opener = urllib2.build_opener() # send the cookies
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies)) # send the cookies
f = opener.open("http://example.com)
```

What will happened two post requests !?

Comment: Read the documentation for urllib2. It will answer your questions on how the library works. If you have specific questions about how to implement logic then post a question. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

The request gets sent when you call the `open()` method on the `opener` object. The `f` variable contain a reference to the open connection in case you want to do something else to it later on (such as close it again).

Your comments that say 'send cookies' are in the wrong place, the line where you call `append` is just preparing the request, it only gets sent when you call `open`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: ok to be clear :) first i'm trying to make one post request contain parameters and specific cookies if i added opener = urllib2.build_opener() # send the cookies
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies)) # send the cookies
f = opener.open("http://example.com") variable f will make another request or the same request ? :)

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.OpenerDirector.open

Comment: in my example when i run the script f variable will make a request ??